# HSEARCH800007 error in Hibernate Search 6.2.2: Unable to resolve path after specifying the indexing dependency

Tags: indexing, hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I have a parent Document class that has subclasses with different types of documents (DocumentInvoice, DocumentReportPublication, etc).

This document can be linked to other documents so I have a ManyToMany association with itself. I have also another method to generate content in the Hibernate Search index only with invoices to store some of the fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
public class Document {

...

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    @KeywordField(name = "title_original", projectable = Projectable.YES, sortable = Sortable.YES, normalizer = "caseInsensitiveNormalizer")
    @FullTextField(name = "title", projectable = Projectable.YES, analyzer = "caseInsensitiveWhitespaceAnalyzer")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "document_linked_document",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "document_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "document_partition_id", referencedColumnName = "document_partition_id")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "linked_document_id", referencedColumnName = "document_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "linked_document_partition_id", referencedColumnName = "document_partition_id")
        })
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {"title"})
    @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)
    private Set<Document> linkedDocuments = new LinkedHashSet<>();

...
@IndexedEmbedded(name = "invoices", includePaths = {
        "title", "paymentReceived", "dateReceived"
    })
    @IndexingDependency(
        derivedFrom = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "linkedDocuments"))
    )
    @AssociationInverseSide(
        inversePath = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "linkedDocuments"))
    )
    public List<DocumentInvoice> getLinkedInvoices() {
        return this.getLinkedDocuments().stream()
            .filter(document -> document instanceof DocumentInvoice)
            .map(document -> (DocumentInvoice) document)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

I have set up the inverse side association so that if there is a change in the linked invoice (for instance the payment status or the amounts) the index gets updated.

It works but I am getting a lot of warnings in the logs:

```
2023-11-29 09:16:56 org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper [WARN] HSEARCH700122: An unexpected failure occurred while configuring resolution of association inverse side for reindexing. This may lead to incomplete reindexing and thus out-of-sync indexes. The exception is being ignored to preserve backwards compatibility with earlier versions of Hibernate Search. Failure: HSEARCH800007: Unable to resolve path '.linkedInvoices' to a persisted attribute in Hibernate ORM metadata. If this path points to a transient attribute, use @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = ...) to specify which persisted attributes it is derived from. See the reference documentation for more information. -- this may indicate a bug or a missing test in Hibernate Search. Please report it: https://hibernate.org/community/ Context: type 'com.penman.core.domain.DocumentInvoice', path '.linkedInvoices<collection>' Association inverse side: {HibernateOrmClassRawTypeModel[com.penman.core.domain.DocumentInvoice]=PojoModelPathValueNode[.linkedDocuments<collection>]}.^M
org.hibernate.search.util.common.AssertionFailure: HSEARCH800007: Unable to resolve path '.linkedInvoices' to a persisted attribute in Hibernate ORM metadata. If this path points to a transient attribute, use @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = ...) to specify which persisted attributes it is derived from. See the reference documentation for more information. -- this may indicate a bug or a missing test in Hibernate Search. Please report it: https://hibernate.org/community/
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.createResolversByOrdinal(PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.java:201) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.createAssociationInverseSideResolver(PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.java:152) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuilder.build(PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuilder.java:114) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.buildOptional(PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.java:132) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.build(PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.building.impl.PojoIndexedTypeManagerBuilder.buildAndAddTo(PojoIndexedTypeManagerBuilder.java:128) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.building.impl.PojoMapper.prepareBuild(PojoMapper.java:287) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.common.impl.SearchIntegrationBuilder$MappingBuildingState.partiallyBuildAndAddTo(SearchIntegrationBuilder.java:288) ~[hibernate-search-engine-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.common.impl.SearchIntegrationBuilder.prepareBuild(SearchIntegrationBuilder.java:189) ~[hibernate-search-engine-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.bootstrap.impl.HibernateSearchPreIntegrationService$NotBooted.doBootFirstPhase(HibernateSearchPreIntegrationService.java:279) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.bootstrap.impl.HibernateOrmIntegrationBooterImpl.bootNow(HibernateOrmIntegrationBooterImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
........
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH800007: Unable to resolve path '.linkedInvoices' to a persisted attribute in Hibernate ORM metadata. If this path points to a transient attribute, use @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = ...) to specify which persisted attributes it is derived from. See the reference documentation for more information.
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.property(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:313) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.property(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:162) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.spi.PojoModelPathBinder.applyPath(PojoModelPathBinder.java:45) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.spi.PojoModelPathBinder.applyPath(PojoModelPathBinder.java:30) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.spi.PojoModelPathBinder.bind(PojoModelPathBinder.java:25) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.interpretPath(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:274) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathDefinitionProvider.interpretPath(HibernateOrmPathDefinitionProvider.java:54) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.impl.PojoRuntimePathsBuildingHelper.toPathDefinition(PojoRuntimePathsBuildingHelper.java:39) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.createResolversByOrdinal(PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.java:175) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        ... 127 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: property [linkedInvoices] not found on entity [com.penman.core.domain.DocumentInvoice]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getProperty(PersistentClass.java:517) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getProperty(PersistentClass.java:528) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.property(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:303) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.property(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:162) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.spi.PojoModelPathBinder.applyPath(PojoModelPathBinder.java:45) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.spi.PojoModelPathBinder.applyPath(PojoModelPathBinder.java:30) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.spi.PojoModelPathBinder.bind(PojoModelPathBinder.java:25) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.interpretPath(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:274) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathDefinitionProvider.interpretPath(HibernateOrmPathDefinitionProvider.java:54) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.impl.PojoRuntimePathsBuildingHelper.toPathDefinition(PojoRuntimePathsBuildingHelper.java:39) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.automaticindexing.building.impl.PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.createResolversByOrdinal(PojoImplicitReindexingResolverBuildingHelper.java:175) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
        ... 127 more
```

As I said DocumentInvoice is one of the subclasses of the Document class, as it is a type of Document:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("INVOICE")
@Table(name = "INVOICE")
@Indexed
@Getter
@Setter
public class DocumentInvoice extends Document {
...
    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    @Column(name="PAYMENT_RECEIVED")
    private Boolean paymentReceived;

    @GenericField(projectable = Projectable.YES)
    @Column(name="DATE_RECEIVED")
    private LocalDate dateReceived;
...
}
```

As suggested in the warning I have set up the @IndexingDependency and the @AssociationInverseSide so I don't understand why we are getting an error. I have tried to move the inverse association to the linkedDocuments property and the result is the same. The documentation shows simpler scenarios and I think it could be related to be doing a relationship with itself.

This seems not to be a problem now, but according to the logs could be an issue in future versions. What are we doing wrong? Could this be an HS6 bug?

EDIT:

At the end adding an extra `@AssociationInverseSide` to the linkedDocuments (so leaving it in both places) and removing the `@IndexingDependency` there made it to work without the error message:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "document_linked_document",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "document_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "document_partition_id", referencedColumnName = "document_partition_id")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "linked_document_id", referencedColumnName = "document_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "linked_document_partition_id", referencedColumnName = "document_partition_id")
        })
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = {"title"})
    @AssociationInverseSide(
        inversePath = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "linkedDocuments"))
    )
    private Set<Document> linkedDocuments = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: Which version of Hibernate Search are you using? Also, please provide compilable code, including classnames, and all relevant classes. You can remove irrelevant fields/methods if necessary, but if you remove class declarations or omit some classes involved in your setup, it's hard to understand; I don't know what `DocumentReportAndPublication` contains, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look. I have edited the question. Hope it gets clearer now. `DocumentReportAndPublication`is another subtype of the Document class, but to make it easier I leave the message that was provoked with DocumentInvoice (all the subclasses generate this warning) so that we just have to deal with 2 classes in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the cause of your problem:

```
@IndexedEmbedded(name = "invoices", includePaths = {
        "title", "paymentReceived", "dateReceived"
    })
    @IndexingDependency(
        derivedFrom = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "linkedDocuments"))
    )
    @AssociationInverseSide(
        inversePath = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "linkedDocuments"))
    )
    public List<DocumentInvoice> getLinkedInvoices() {
```

Because Hibernate Search assumes annotations refer to "extracted" elements by default, the `IndexingDependency` annotation basically says "elements of `linkedInvoices` are derived from elements of `linkedDocuments`".

Whereas what you need to tell Hibernate Search is "the (whole) list `linkedInvoices` is derived from elements of `linkedDocuments`". Otherwise Hibernate Search will try to resolve `linkedInvoices` as an association first, which obviously won't work.

I know it's not intuitive (at all), though. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4271 should hopefully fix this one day, when we get time to work on it.

EDIT: Also, you should probably remove the `@AssociationInverseSide` from `getLinkedInvoices`, as I don't think this really is the inverse side of `linkedDocuments`.

This should work better:

```java
@IndexedEmbedded(name = "invoices", includePaths = {
        "title", "paymentReceived", "dateReceived"
    })
    @IndexingDependency(
        derivedFrom = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "linkedDocuments")),
        // ADD THIS
        extraction = @ContainerExtraction(extract = ContainerExtract.NO)
    )
    public List<DocumentInvoice> getLinkedInvoices() {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I think you found the root of the issue. Unfortunately I have made the proposed change and now it is worse, from a warning we have gone to an error and the application does not start:
`org.hibernate.search.util.common.SearchException: HSEARCH800007: Unable to resolve path '.linkedInvoices' to a persisted attribute in Hibernate ORM metadata. If this path points to a transient attribute, use @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = ...) to specify which persisted attributes it is derived from. See the reference documentation for more information.
`

Comment: For more context:
at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.property(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:313) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
 at org.hibernate.search.mapper.orm.model.impl.HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.property(HibernateOrmPathInterpreter.java:162) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-orm-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
 at org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.model.path.spi.PojoModelPathBinder.applyPath(PojoModelPathBinder.java:45) ~[hibernate-search-mapper-pojo-base-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
...

Comment: And the error logged: 
`2023-11-30 10:59:10 org.hibernate.search.engine.reporting.spi.RootFailureCollector [ERROR] HSEARCH000521: Hibernate Search encountered a failure during bootstrap; continuing for now to list all problems, but the process will ultimately be aborted.
Context: Hibernate ORM mapping, type 'com.penman.core.domain.DocumentInvoice'`

Comment: But it is happening in all the docment subclasses

Comment: @lechonex You should remove the `@AssociationInverseSide` from `getLinkedInvoices`, as I don't think this really is the inverse side of `linkedDocuments`. I updated my answer. This may lead to more errors about `linkedDocuments` not having an inverse side. If that happens, I suggest you add that inverse side to your entities (a new field annotated with `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "linkedDocuments")`). See this somewhat relevant section of the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-automatic-concepts-session-consistency

Comment: As expected removing the `@AssociationInverseSide` lead to a `HSEARCH700020: Unable to find the inverse side of the association` error. I don't understand how I would add a new field linkedDocuments are an association with the Document class itself (a document linked to other documents) and linkedInvoices is not really an attribute, but just a getter to create indexes.

Comment: "I don't understand how I would add a new field". Well, something like this: `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "linkedDocuments") private List<Document> documentsLinkingToThis;`. Note you will need to keep that list up to date; see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-automatic-concepts-session-consistency. Though a few helper methods can help you deal with that: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: So you are suggesting I have in the same class two attributes referring to the same thing? Should  I have 2 `@ManyToMany` associations for linkedDocuments, one of them with "`mappedBy? Is that the only way to make it work without warnings? I just want to be sure I am understanding correctly

Comment: They don't refer to the same thing, they refer to two sides of your association. All associations have a direction. If you do `doc1.getLinkedDocuments().add(doc2)`, then `doc2.getLinkedDocuments()` won't magically contain `doc1`, even after reloading it from the database. If you use `@IndexedEmbedded` on one side of your association, when embedded entities change, Hibernate Search needs is to go through the association in the opposite direction, to know what to reindex. That's what this `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = ...)` is used for.

Comment: If you're sure `linkedDocuments` is always perfectly symmetrical (`doc1.getLinkedDocuments()` containing `doc2` is equivalent to `doc2.getLinkedDocuments()` containing `doc1`), either through database mapping magic or through application code always updating both sides of the association, then you can avoid the `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = ...)` and put `@AssociationInverseSide(inversePath = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "linkedDocuments")))` directly on `linkedDocuments`. But that is *only* safe if you're *sure* about the association being symmetrical.

Comment: I am sure about the association being symmetrical, we control it in the code, but adding `@AssociationInverseSide` to linkedDocuments didn't help. Actually we got again an error instead of a warning. I have tried putting the annotation in both places and just in one (any of them), adding and removing the extraction and the only thing that kind of works is what I had at the beginning but I still have the odd warning. Do you want me to add the errors I have for each case?

Comment: Yes, I need the stacktraces to help.

Comment: I have edited the question with the final fix. trying all the solutions I could imagine to prepare the stacktraces for you I found the solution. Do you see any problem with it? Thanks again for your time, it has helped me to understand HS6 better and to find the fix.

Comment: Just for clarification, at the end I have not used the ContainerExtraction annotation

Comment: I don't really understand why the pre-existing `@AssociationInverseSide` (the one on `linkedInvoices`) is necessary, but if it works... Glad you managed to fix it :)